# Type mismatch - VBA - Microsoft access

Tags: vba, ms-access, parsing, types

Please help. I am trying to validate the username and password from another table. The below code gives me "Type mismatch error". I have no idea why. Please help.

```
If (DLookup("[UserLogin]", "Sheet1", _
 "[UserLogin] ='" & Me.txtloginid.Value & "' And [Password] = '" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'")) Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if *UserLogin* is numeric.

Also, don't rely on *Null* values for logic operations:

```vb
If Not IsNull(DLookup("[UserLogin]", "Sheet1", _
    "[UserLogin] = " & Me.txtloginid.Value & " And [Password] = '" & Me.txtpassword.Value & "'")) Then
```

Comment: Is there any other options to validate username and password in access ? I want the page to be terminated if username & pwd is either blank or wrong values being entered. Please advise.

Comment: There are many methods and options, and this is one of them. It will , if _UserLogin_ is text (as in your question) also work for empty textboxes. Of course, _Sheet1_ must be a table or query.